# Defining routes in api.php and web.php with same name

Tags: laravel, api, routes

I have a route in my `api.php` file

```
Route::get('category/{id}/subcategory','SubcategoryController@categoryFinder')->name('cat_to_sub.find');
```

This route worked fine until i added another route in the `web.php` file

```
Route::get('category/{id}/subcategory',function(){return view('subcategories');});
```

And then when i `run php artisan route:list`
The URI `api/category/{id}/subcategory` has no name and i referenced that name all over my files and its throwing all these errors saying `route cat_to_sub.find not defined`

But when i remove the route in the `web.php` file everything works.
So whats causing this errors and is there another way to do it?

Comment: You are overwriting the first route with 2nd.

Comment: Ok but is there any workarounds?

Comment: Try this in app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php: call mapWebRoutes() before mapApiRoutes() in the map() method. Didn't try it but this should work.

Comment: You can only define a route once, otherwise, the server would not know which to call. Why are you defining the route twice?

Comment: I am using vue.js on the frontend...the api route gives me all subcategories within a certain category id...so i have multiple "a" tags with a url like category/12/subcategory..when this url is called i wanna load the subcategories view which will display all subcategories with a category id of 12